# How do you set the name of a Azure SQL Server in C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

In the Azure Portal you can set the name of the SQL Server (not database).

[image: Azure Portal]

How do you set the name in C#?

(using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Sql.5.2.0)

```
var result = client.Servers.CreateAsync(new ServerCreateParameters
{
   AdministratorUserName = config.ServerUserName,
   AdministratorPassword = config.ServerPassword,
   Location = config.Location,
   Version = config.Version
}, CancellationToken.None).Result;

var serverName = result.ServerName;
```

Comment: U can't set the instance name of an azure SQL database last I knew.

Comment: I can set the database name, just not the server in c# (I can do both in the portal)
 `client.Databases.CreateAsync(serverName, new 
DatabaseCreateParameters
                {
                    Name = databaseName,`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The preview version of the API supports this:

```
 var result = client.Servers.CreateOrUpdateAsync(
      _resourceGroupName, "my-Server", new ServerCreateOrUpdateParameters...
```

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/sql-database-client-library/

Answer (score 4):

This still isn't possible from the API.  It was originally by design - from https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-dotnet-how-to-use/:

> Notice that you did not specify a server name. SQL Database auto-generates the server name to ensure there are no duplicate DNS entries. The server name is a ten-character alphanumeric string. You cannot change the name of your SQL Database server.

The new portal has been updated to allow this functionality now, but the C# API hasn't caught up yet.